# xsd extension sequence of extension-elements

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I would like to specify using xsd an xml-file of the form:

```
<root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test2.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
  <mult>
    <end />
    <one>
      <end />
    </one>        
    <end />
    <mult>
      <end />
    </mult>
    <mult />
  </mult>
</root>
```

That is, both, mult and end, instantiate a common abstract-type.
I am not clear how to define the type for mult without introducing further xml-elements as follows:

```
<root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test2.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
  <mult>
    <value>
        <end />
    </value>
    <value>
        <one>
            <end />
        </one>
    </value>
    <value>
        <end />
    </value>
    <value>
        <mult>
            <value>
                <end />
            </value>
        </mult>
    </value>
    <value>
        <mult />
    </value>
  </mult>
</root>
```

for this latter file I can use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:complexType name="TYPE_end" />

<xs:complexType name="TYPE_one">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="TYPE_abstract" />
    </xs:complexContent>                
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TYPE_mult">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="value" type="TYPE_one" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TYPE_abstract">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="end" type="TYPE_end" />
        <xs:element name="one"  type="TYPE_one" />
        <xs:element name="mult"  type="TYPE_mult" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:element name="root" type="TYPE_abstract"/>

</xs:schema>
```

However, I do not know how to avoid the additional value-tag.
I could duplicate the list of elements as in the following example but this duplication is not nice as well...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:complexType name="TYPE_end" />

<xs:complexType name="TYPE_one">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="TYPE_abstract" />
    </xs:complexContent>                
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TYPE_mult">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="end" type="TYPE_end" />
            <xs:element name="one"  type="TYPE_one" />
            <xs:element name="mult"  type="TYPE_mult" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="TYPE_abstract">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="end" type="TYPE_end" />
        <xs:element name="one"  type="TYPE_one" />
        <xs:element name="mult"  type="TYPE_mult" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:element name="root" type="TYPE_abstract"/>

</xs:schema>
```

Any ideas how to provide a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the rules for your XML, the following looks like it would work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML 2016 Developer Bundle Edition 14.1.4.6649 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="TYPE_abstract">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="end" />
            <xs:element name="one" type="TYPE_abstract" />
            <xs:element name="mult" type="TYPE_abstract" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="root" type="TYPE_abstract" />
</xs:schema>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, it is not the solution as the xsd you provided allows "one" to have not exactly one descendant. I am still interested in a solution ;-)